# Showing up the "variable" not the number Python

Tags: python, append, label

I am newbie here. Sorry for this silly question.

I am trying to count words, for example "Positive", "Negative", and "Neutral" in many .txt file (3979 files). After I count it, I would like to pick one with the highest count.

Let's say in a given text, there are 5 Positive, 1 Negative, and 0 Neutral.

I put it in a list such as

```
myRev = [Positive, Negative, Neutral]
```

Then if I use

```
largest = max(myRev)
```

and when I call `largest`, it will gives

```
5
```

**In this case, I want the value to show up is `Positive`, `Negative`, or `Neutral`** (>>> this is my main question)

After that I would like to put the `Positive`, `Negative`, or `Neutral` into another list which I append in like this...

```
ReviewList = []
ReviewList.append(maxNr)
```

and I wish if I call the `ReviewList` become something like

```
Reviewlist = [Positive, Negative, Neutral, Neutral,... Neutral]
```

and so on..

What can I do for that? I am so clueless, and have tried reading as many as possible but I am just getting more confused with it...

Here is of my - not so confident - code:

```
listOfReview = []

for i in xrange(0,3979):
    f = open("ReviewsOutput%i.txt" %i, "r")
    myOutput = f.read()
    Positive = myOutput.count("Positive")
    Negative = myOutput.count("Negative")
    Neutral = myOutput.count("Neutral")
    myRev = [Positive, Negative, Neutral]
    largest = max(myRev)
    listOfReview.append(largest)
    f.close
```

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: Hehe, I am not so confident about it :(
But I have added my code on my question...

Comment: Take a look at `collections.Counter` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary {'positive':5, 'negative':1, 'negative':0}

```
>>> review = {'positive':5, 'negative':1, 'negative':0}
>>> maxNr = max(review, key=review.get)
>>> maxNr
'positive'
>>> ReviewList = []
>>> ReviewList.append(maxNr)
>>> ReviewList
['positive']
```

Edit:
You can try this :

```
listOfReview = []
review = {'Positive':0, 'Negative':0, 'Neutral':0}

for i in xrange(0,3979):
    f = open("ReviewsOutput%i.txt" %i, "r")
    myOutput = f.read()
    review['Positive'] = myOutput.count("Positive")
    review['Negative'] = myOutput.count("Negative")
    review['Neutral'] = myOutput.count("Neutral")
    largest = max(review, key=review.get)
    listOfReview.append(largest)
    f.close
```

You also can get the review count by calling review[largest].

Comment: I don't really understand how to use the dictionary. Because this is thousands of file, it's impossible to do if I were to add manually all of it. There must be something I could do in loop, and automatically add it into a list...and append all of it. That's the thing that I really have no clue.
Sorry, but I really have no background in programming and I really need step by step to do it for thousands of file..

Comment: Hey, this solved my problem!!
I finally figured it out after hours tweaking it. Thank you so much @SDBot :)